# Http get/post for encoded String

Tags: java, android, base64, inputstream

i have question about sending and getting the encoded data for image. Firstly i have image as Base64 encoded type in String, this string has a value such as below :
**...D/2wBDAA0JCgsKCA0LCgsODg0PEyAVExISEyccHhcgLikxMC4pLSwzOko+MzZ...**

Now if i decode again and if i use BitmapFactory to accomodate on imageview thats all right the image is ok.

```
byte[] bytes= stream.toByteArray();                               
imagestr=Base64.encodeBytes(bytes).toString();
//If i code below it is working
byte[] decode = Base64.decode(imagestr);
decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decode, 0, decode.length);

//If i send to the server and handle it in servlet file
String pic = request.getParameter("p");
byte[] servdec = Base64.decode(pic);
//and if i use the servdec to output a image file file is corrupted.
//I noticed the pic and imagestr are different 
//imagestr = **...D/2wBDAA0JCgsKCA0LCgsODg0PEyAVExISEyccHhcgLikxMC4pLSwzOko+MzZ...**
//pic      = **...D/2wBDAA0JCgsKCA0LCgsODg0PEyAVExISEyccHhcgLikxMC4pLSwzOko MzZ...**
//pic has no + sign.
```

I used replaceAll but it is only for this case. It may cause more prob. so is there any solution can you advice thank you for your answers...

Hi, this string is in pic which comes to this function, after this function servlet will handle this !pic has + sign in this function
    public String uuidfaceid(String uuid,String faceid, String name,String pic){

```
URL url = null;

try {

url = new
```

URL("http://"+Constants.SERVER_NAME+Constants.SERVER_PORT+"/MeetInTouch/UF"+"?
uuid="+uuid+"&faceid="+faceid+"&name="+name+"&pic="+pic);

```
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {

e1.printStackTrace();

}

URLConnection ucon = null;

try {

ucon = url.openConnection();

} catch (IOException e1) {

e1.printStackTrace();

}

try {

ucon.connect();

} catch (IOException e1) {

e1.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with escaping - spaces are replaced with `+` for `application/x-www-form-encoded`. You should probably escape the string before sending - show us how you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter that "p" that contains the Base64 encoded string has been "url decoded" at some point. All you have to do is encode it again before you try to decode the Base64:

```
String pic = request.getParameter("p");
pic = URLEncoder.encode(pic, "ISO-8859-1");
byte[] servdec = Base64.decode(pic);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer i tried ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, UTF-16 / changing to % and some more...

Comment: No it did not help but thank you, i also tried URLDecoder.decode(pic,"ISO-8859-9");